# Lumia 925 won't connect to cellular network

Tags: cellular, lumia-925

I tried it with a few T-Mobile SIM cards, all of then work fine on other Lumia devices (same location, same SIM, different device).

Tried resetting the phone and flashing it back to 8.0, still won't connect.

Is there anything else I can do other than sending it to Nokia?

Comment: At the top of the screen, does it show no signal, or a SIM error?

Comment: It was no signal with several SIM cards. Ended up sending it to Nokia for repair

Comment: The method  "cycle airplane mode" should do the trick to make this work.

Answer (score 2):

Several reasons what is wrong:

- The device is locked to be used only for specific SIM
- The device is set up to manually search and register to another network (other than T-Mobile)

Settings - Network + SIM - Setting of SIM - Search automatically for network

- The SIM is somewhat wrong (blocked, or inserted wrong way)

Comment: As I mentioned in the question, this is a Lumia 925 (a T-Mobile device) and I've tried it with several SIM cards.

I had to send it to Nokia for repair (free shipping and one week total time, so not so bad)

Comment: There are multiple variants of Lumia 925. Only one of the variants is intended for use with T-Mobile US. My sister's 925 is from Europe, and only works on TMo because it is unlocked; even then, it doesn't get LTE.